# Is it grammatically correct help me ,with proper explanation,with tense explanation

Tags: british-english, tenses, syntactic-analysis, verb-agreement, sentence-patterns

You were got bored, weren't you?
It that correct ,can we use all verbs in past tense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say:
You were bored, weren't you? OR
You got bored, didn't you? 
Combining were and got in the same clause isn't gramatically correct. Of course, using the verbs in the past tense sounds perfectly correct.

Comment: One more question I am being torn apart or I am being tear apart ,what is difference and why?